# heroku console commands add category

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I deployed my rails app to Heroku. I am trying to use the Heroku console to add categories to my app but I do not know the commands.

Controller:

```
class PortfolioController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
   end

   def about
   end

   def portfolio
   end

   def contact
   end

   def webapp
     category = Category.find_by_category('webapp')
     @posts = Post.where(category_id: category.id)
   end

  def art
    category = Category.find_by_category('gameart')
    @posts = Post.where(category_id: category.id)
  end
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160910220215) do

create_table "admins", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
end

add_index "admins", ["email"], name: "index_admins_on_email", unique: true
add_index "admins", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admins_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "category"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "content"
t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
t.integer  "category_id"
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a category in the rails/heroku console under your table `Categories` simply run:

```
Category.connection
```

Then:

```
Category.create(name: "NAME_OF_CATEGORY")
```

It will then create a category as such:

```
#<Category id: 1, name: "NAME_OF_CATEGORY", created_at: "2016-09-14 22:25:14", updated_at: "2016-09-14 22:25:14">
```